# Component uses font before Font.loadAsync finishes React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, expo

I have this code for my mobile app that I was building using react native and expo where even when I'm using async await for the pre-loading of the custom font, my component still uses it before Font.loadAsync finishes. I was wondering why this happens even tho I maintain a state **mainScreenIsReady** that checks if my assets have finished loading and only then render the main component but the error `You need to wait for Font.loadAsync to complete before using the font` still persists:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import Entypo from "@expo/vector-icons/Entypo";

function cacheImages(images) {
    return images.map((image) => {
        if (typeof image === "string") {
            return Image.prefetch(image);
        } else {
            return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
        }
    });
}

function cacheFonts(fonts) {
    return fonts.map((font) => Font.loadAsync(font));
}

export default function MainScreen() {
    const [mainScreenIsReady, setMainScreenIsReady] = useState(false);

    // Load any resources or data that you need before rendering the app
    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadResourcesAndDataAsync() {
            try {
                const imageAssets = cacheImages([]);

                const fontAssets = cacheFonts([
                    Entypo.font,
                    // font that I'm loading
                    Font.loadAsync({
                        SFProBold: require("../assets/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Bold.otf"),
                    }),
                ]);

                await Promise.all([...imageAssets, ...fontAssets]);
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn(e);
            } finally {
                setMainScreenIsReady(true);
            }
        }

        loadResourcesAndDataAsync();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {mainScreenIsReady && (
                <View
                    style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
                >
                    <!-- the font gets used immediately before Font.loadAsync finishes -->
                    <Text style={{ fontFamily: "SFProBold" }}>SplashScreen Demo! </Text>
                    <Entypo name="rocket" size={30} />
                </View>
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, fixed it by removing the redundant **Font.loadAsync** when calling the **cacheFonts** function since it already applies **Font.loadAsync** for each item of its array argument.

```js
// ...
const fontAssets = cacheFonts([
    Entypo.font,
    // font that I'm loading, removed Font.loadAsync
    {
        SFProBold: require("../assets/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Bold.otf"),
    },
]);
// ...
```